# What depth of discharge does 0% in a UPS correspond to?

Tags: power-supply, battery, battery-life, ups

When a UPS like an APC Smart-UPS shows 0% charge remaining, does it mean the deep-cycle batteries are completely discharged or that they're at 20%?

Comment: This is an old post.  Looks like you never got a response, probably because nobody outside of APC is likely to know the answer precisely.  However, my guess would be neither.  The relevant number to report is the charge that the UPS can use to power your computer.  In order to produce the output voltage, some minimum battery voltage is required.  0% is probably associated with whatever that voltage threshold is.  The actual battery charge at which it drops below the threshold could be higher than 20%.  If battery charge was reported, it would crap out while it still showed charge remaining.